# Path helper for rails route, with param that mounts an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

Hi I have the following route:

```
mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => ':city_name/', :as => :spree
```

that produces urls like `/munich/path/in/engine` or `/new_york/path/in/engine`

How can I use an url helper to produce such an url, that modifies the city and uses an url helper of the engine? If the engine would provide an url helper for a product (e.g. `product_path(@product)`), is there something like

```
spree_path(:city_name => "munich").product_path(@product)
```

to produce an url like `/munich/products/1`?

Answer (score 0):

This should just work, using:

```
spree.product_path(@product, :city_name => "munich")
```

Comment: this is generating http://localhost:3000/salzburg/products/dell-laptop?city_name=munich if i am in a city with name salzburg (inside the engine)

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use Engine's own url helpers:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.url_helpers.product_path
```